# Unable to install rmarkdown packages

Tags: r, package, install.packages

Here's what I got...

```r
** Installing R Package Dependencies for R Markdown: 'rmarkdown', 'stringi'
[1/2] Installing rmarkdown...
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rmarkdown_2.9.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3246617 bytes (3.1 MB)
================================================[2/2] Installing stringi...

downloaded 3.0 MB

Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  download from 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rmarkdown_2.9.tar.gz' failed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  downloaded length 3152276 != reported length 3246617

2: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rmarkdown_2.9.tar.gz': Timeout of 60 seconds was reached

Warning in download.packages(pkgs, destdir = tmpd, available = available,  :
  download of package ‘rmarkdown’ failed

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.1/stringi_1.7.3.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 14636855 bytes (14.0 MB)

=========
downloaded 2.7 MB

Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  download from 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.1/stringi_1.7.3.tgz' failed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  downloaded length 2835937 != reported length 14636855

2: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.1/stringi_1.7.3.tgz': Timeout of 60 seconds was reached
Warning in download.packages(pkgs, destdir = tmpd, available = available,  :
  download of package ‘stringi’ failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop all of that output after the first mention of `Timeout of 60 seconds was reached`. It appears you are experiencing network glitches, and R is not adapting to them well.

Three suggestions:

- increase R's timeout, per @Phil's answer;
- keep trying with `install.packages(..)` until it finally works, hoping luck will eventually smile on you; or
- download externally, verify the files downloaded, then install manually.

Assuming the third, then using firefox/chrome/safari (or whatever you prefer), download the URLs present in your R console *manually* to a directory. I'll assume the local directory, but you can save them to where-ever you prefer.

```r
AP <- available.packages()
AP[AP[,1] %in% c("rmarkdown", "stringi"),c("Package", "Version", "MD5sum", "Repository")]
#           Package     Version MD5sum                             Repository                            
# rmarkdown "rmarkdown" "2.9"   "acd82da6a09f8e6564595dfa9039e032" "https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib"
# stringi   "stringi"   "1.7.3" "94c37221840cd9f5b7545c585d0c6b07" "https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib"
```

```r
system("md5sum rmarkdown_2.9.tar.gz")
# acd82da6a09f8e6564595dfa9039e032 *rmarkdown_2.9.tar.gz
# [1] 0
```

(and repeat for `stringi`).

Assuming that the checksums match, then you can do

```r
install.packages(c("rmarkdown_2.9.tar.gz", "stringi_1.7.3.tgz"), repos = NULL)
```

to install the downloaded files.

Comment: Thank you for the three plans! I'm trying the 1200 for now and will try the third plan if it not works!

Answer (score 1):

The error is that the timeout of 60 seconds is reached (i.e. it's taking too long to download). A workaround is to increase the `timeout` time:

```
options(timeout=120)
```

Or maybe longer if you need it

Comment: Hi Phil, thank you for the solution! I tried 120 but it seems that I need more time so I'm trying 1200 right now...will let you know how it works!

Comment: @EvelynYang no problem. Consider upvoting if it helped. Consider accepting r2evans's answer as that's probably more helpful to future readers.